# .htaccess not redirecting successfully for pretty url's

Tags: php, .htaccess

My .htaccess is as follows:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./backend-scripts/url_parser.php
```

and then, handling the url redirect is the file url_parser.php which is as follows.

```
<?php

// open file and get its contents in a string format.
$string = file_get_contents("../json/site_map.json");

// decode the json string into an associative array.
$jsonArray = json_decode($string, TRUE);

// add trailing slash to URI if its not there.
$requestURI = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$requestURI .= $requestURI[ strlen($requestURI) - 1 ] == "/" ? "" : "/";

// split up the URL at slashes.
$uriArray = explode('/', $requestURI);

// select the last piece of exploded array as key.
$uriKey = $uriArray[count($uriArray)-2];

// lookup the key in sitemap
// retrieve the absolute file URL.
$absPath = $jsonArray[$uriKey];

// reformulate the URL.
$path = "../$absPath";

// include the actual page.
include($path);

?>
```

in order to test my php code, I replaced

```
$requestURI = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

by the following:

```
$requestURI = "/welcome";
```

and it worked perfectly. So I'm pretty sure that there is something wrong inside my .htaccess file. How can I change that?

Comment: You're performing a pattern match and capturing the request, however you don't do anything with it.

Comment: can you elaborate exactly how should I do that? It'll be really helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: Not clear what exactly isn't working in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./backend-scripts/url_parser.php
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./backend-scripts/url_parser.php?url=$1
```

Then  change `$requestURI = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` to:

```
$requestURI = (!empty($_GET['url']))
    ? $_GET['url']
    : ''; // no url supplied
```

---

**WARNING:** Do not pass user supplied values to `include()`. Make sure the paths are checked against a proper whitelist, otherwise a malicious user can hijack your server.